# Find cluster/subgraph of nodes in dot

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, dot, pydot

I have a dot file that contains a graph having different clusters, something like:

```
subgraph cluster_bb_5020 {
            style=filled fillcolor=white
            label="label  [5020]"
            NODE230 [label="668"]
            ....
```

I wonder how I can get the cluster number of nodes (e.g. here cluster of  NODE230 is cluster_bb_5020) in the graph by networkx or pydot or pygraphviz? Or in general, how I can get cluster informations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
import pydot   
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('graph.dot')
nodes_bb = {}
for cluster in graph[0].get_subgraphs():
     if cluster.obj_dict['name'].startswith('cluster_bb_'):
          basic_block_id = cluster.obj_dict['name'].split('_')[-1]
               for node in cluster.obj_dict['nodes'].keys():
                    nodes_bb[node] = str(basic_block_id)

print nodes_bb
```

However, pydot is really slow!!!